# Vnc viewer authentication failure

Tags: vnc

I recently backed up my data and I had moved the vnc viewer executable from my PC to my portable hard disk.

Realizing that I no longer had vnc, I got the latest one,
but all of a sudden I could not connect to my server anymore and got authentification failure.

So I moved the VNC exectuable back from my portable HD to my local HD.
And I am still getting Authentification failure errors.

I had a certain setup and I don't want to re-create it,
do you know how I can recover or what happened to get auth failures all of a sudden ?

I checked and the vncserver process is running fine.
Old VNC viewer: vnc-4_1_3-x86_win32_viewer.exe
New one:

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the server and viewer are the same versions.  VNC is not a complicated application to setup.  Worse case spent the 5mins to re-set it up.  Another solution to consider is [TeamViewer.](http://www.teamviewer.com/)  It has better functionality then VNC, is encrypted and does not require port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem, because I entered my linux user password, which was different for the vnc password.

The password for the vncviewer is stored in `~/.vnc/passwd`.
One can delete it, and when creating a new session with `vncserver`, it asks for a new password.